# Displaying alert twice instead of single time with rails render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

I want to alert the user about the domain .

When I using below way I got the issues that alert is displaying twice .

Due to some code structure I need to write javascript like that.

My controller code is like :

```
render :text => "alert('The entered email is not registered domain')"
```

I have tried partial in controller like :

```
render :partial => 'folder/user_alert'
```

and partial (`_user_alert.html.erb`) like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('The entered email is not registered domain')
</script>
```

Comment: What are you doing with the resulting `<script>` tag? Is it rendered with AJAX? Are you `eval`'ing it, inserting it in the DOM? You could put a lot more detail in your question, particularly for the client-side code.

Comment: Its rendering through Ajax... and I have used eval . And have nothing more in client side ... 
Steps are like :
1) Making ajax call to check the insert email has registered domain or not . 
2) If its not registered domain than I will render this alert message and submit the form from here ...
Hope this will easy to understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to follow another architecture:

```
 render :text => 'The entered email is not registered domain', :status=>500
```

now you can select with your Javascript what exactly you want to do (alert, or show in messages etc)